# WSO2 APIM 1.10.0 error with IdP initiated SSO: "Invalid argument. Relay state value is missing."

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-api-manager

I have WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 configured for IdP initiated SSO with PingFederate. When I try to access publisher URL, it logs in fine and I got the right SAML response.

But the UI threw the error:

```
Error 500 : The page cannot be displayed.

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

The server side has:

```
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: **Invalid argument. Relay state value is missing.**
    at org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso.SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject.jsFunction_getRelayStateProperty(SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject.java:868)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 50 more
```

Does WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 support ***IdP initiated SSO only*** at all?

***UPDATE: Per reply below, the best option is to upgrade to >2.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIM 1.10.0 does not have the support for IDP intitiated SSO. However, it is supported in APIM 2.1.0. Refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+API+Manager+for+SSO).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That explains why it threw the error even if we tried many ways. Wish the documantation for WSO2 APIM 1.10.0 was more clear on that.

Comment: Accepted this as an answer, also updated in my post: The solution is to upgrade.

Comment: I am getting close: Now after adding TargetResource parameter I got: 404 error. WSO2 APIM Server log has: Relaystate value is invalid . What does that mean, and what should be valid Relaystate? I set TargetResoyurce as publisher URL.